# correct usage of compare_exchange_weak

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, clang++, lock-free

```
const int SIZE = 20; 
struct Node { Node* next; };

std::atomic<Node*> head (nullptr);
void push (void* p)
{
    Node* n = (Node*) p;
    n->next = head.load (); 
    while (!head.compare_exchange_weak (n->next, n));
}
void* pop ()
{
    Node* n = head.load (); 
    while (n &&
          !head.compare_exchange_weak (n, n->next));

    return n ? n : malloc (SIZE);
}

void thread_fn()
{
    std::array<char*, 1000> pointers;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) pointers[i] = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {   
        int r = random() % 1000;

        if (pointers[r] != nullptr) // allocated earlier
        {   
            push (pointers[r]);
            pointers[r] = nullptr;
        }   
        else
        {   
            pointers[r] = (char*) pop (); // allocate

            // stamp the memory
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                pointers[r][i] = 0xEF;
        }   
    }   
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N = 8;

   std::vector<std::thread*> threads;
   threads.reserve (N);

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       threads.push_back (new std::thread (thread_fn));

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       threads[i]->join();
}
```

What is wrong with this usage of compare_exchange_weak ? The above code crashes 1 in 5 times using clang++ (MacOSX).

The head.load() at the time of the crash will have "0xEFEFEFEFEF". `pop` is like malloc and `push` is like free. Each thread (8 threads) randomly allocate or deallocate memory from `head`

Comment: Your title mentions `compare_exchange_weak` but your code uses `compare_exchange_strong`. Which one is it?

Comment: It crashes for both `compare_exchange_weak` and `compare_exchange_strong`.

Comment: Why are you returning `malloc(20)` in `pop()` when `n==nullptr`? Shouldn't you just return `nullptr`?

Comment: It is part of a allocator, that maintains a list of fixed size allocations. So if there is not a free block available, then allocate and return. Therefore it is `malloc (20)` not `nullptr`

Comment: Please show complete sample and point where it crashes. I believe, your pop() is broken, but it depends on how you use these functions.

Comment: updated code with the driver function.

Answer (score 1):

It could be nice *lock-free* allocator, but [ABA-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) arise:

**A**: Assume, that some `thread1` executes `pop()`, which reads current value of `head` into `n` variable, but immediately after this the thread is preemted and *concurrent* `thread2` executes full `pop()` call, that is it reads same value from `head` and performs *successfull* `compare_exchange_weak`.

**B**: Now object, referred by `n` in the `thread1`, has no longer belonged to the list, and can be modified by `thread2`. So `n->next` is garbage in general: reading from it can return any value. For example, it can be `0xEFEFEFEFEF`, where the first 5 bytes are *stamp* (`EF`), witch has been written by `thread2`, and the last 3 bytes are still `0`, from *nullptr*. (Total value is numerically interpreted in *little-endian* manner). It seems that, because `head` value has been changed, `thread1` will fail its `compare_exchange_weak` call, but...

**A**: Concurrent `thread2` `push()`es resulted pointer **back into the list**. So `thread1` sees initial value of `head`, and perform successfull `compare_exchange_weak`, which writes *incorrect* value into `head`. List is corrupted.

Note, that problem is more than possibility, that other thread can modify content of `n->next`. The problem is that value of `n->next` **is no longer coupled with the list**. So, even it is not modified concurrently, it becomes invalid (for replace `head`) in case, e.g., when other thread(s) `pop()` 2 elements from the list but `push()` back only first of them. (So `n->next` will points to the second element, which is has no longer belonged to the list.)

Comment: @venkat: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.